# Setting codecov patch target to a fixed number

Tags: code-coverage

codecov allows you to specify a total coverage target and it also allows codecov/patch. The patch check however attempts to enforce that the patch coverage is atleast at current master's coverage. i.e. if total coverage target is 80% and if current master coverage is 84%, the patch coverage needs to be atleast 84%. I understand the rationale behind this, that codecov is not allowing the total coverage to regress...

My question is this - Is there a way at all to specify a fixed target for the patch coverage ? For e.g., let's say I want to set my patch coverage target to a fixed 80% as well, is there any way at all to do that ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14):

Yes, the documentation is here: https://docs.codecov.io/docs/commit-status

You can create a `.codecov.yml` file at the root of the project with the following:

```
coverage:
  status:
    patch:
      default:
        target: 80%
```